# Function with other function as variable

Tags: matlab, octave

I have to write a function in octave, of the form f(fun,x,m) where fun is another function 
but i have a problem with that, how can i do such thing? (put a function as variable)

Comment: @HelloWorld - your suggestion is not so good. Please look at the answer of [Roney](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15996903/1714410) - using function handles. please remove your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "function handles".

As per the article given [here](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html),

> handle = @functionname %returns a handle to the specified MATLAB® function.

A function handle is a MATLAB value that provides a means of calling a function indirectly. You can pass function handles in calls to other functions (often called function functions). You can also store function handles in data structures for later use (for example, as Handle Graphics callbacks). A function handle is one of the standard MATLAB data types.

The following example creates a function handle for the inbuilt `humps` function and assigns it to the variable `fhandle`.

```
fhandle = @humps;
```

Now you can pass the handle to another function in the same way you would pass any argument. This example passes the function handle just created to `fminbnd`, which then minimizes over the interval `[0.3, 1]`.

```
x = fminbnd(fhandle, 0.3, 1)
x =
    0.6370
```